# How can I predict memory usage and time based on historical values

Tags: math, memory, statistics, forecasting

A maths problem really I think...
I have some historical data for some spreadsheet outputs along with the number of rows and columns.

What I'd like to do is use this data to predict the peak memory usage and time taken based on the - known - row and columns.

So, if no historical data exists then there will be no predictions. 1 or 2 historical values will be very inaccurate but I hope that given a wide enough variety of historical values, then a reasonably-accurate prediction could be made?

I've got a table on a jsfiddle. Any help or ideas would be really appreciated. I don't really know where to start on this one.

http://jsfiddle.net/JelbyJohn/kwje9chf/3/

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fit a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) model.

Since this is a programming site, here is some [R](http://www.r-project.org/) code:

```
> d <- read.table("data.tsv", sep="\t", header=T)
> summary(lm(log(Bytes.RAM) ~ log(Rows) + log(Columns), d))

Call:
lm(formula = log(Bytes.RAM) ~ log(Rows) + log(Columns), data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4800 -0.2409 -0.1618  0.1729  0.6827 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  12.42118    0.61820  20.093 8.72e-09 ***
log(Rows)     0.51032    0.09083   5.618 0.000327 ***
log(Columns)  0.58200    0.07821   7.441 3.93e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.4052 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9062, Adjusted R-squared: 0.8853 
F-statistic: 43.47 on 2 and 9 DF,  p-value: 2.372e-05
```

This model explains the data pretty well (the [R²](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) is 0.89) and suggests the following relationship between the size of the spreadsheet and memory usage:

```
Bytes.RAM = exp(12.42 + 0.51 * log(Rows) + 0.58 * log(Columns))
```

A similar model can be used to predict the execution time (the `Seconds` column). There, the R² is `0.998`.

Comment: This looks brilliant albeit a bit over my head right now. I'm working my way through it trying to make sense of it.

Comment: It seems like I break this down into two useful parts: 
1) the end equation which are based on constants derived from...
2) the calculation of the constants

This is useful as I can write a task to define/update the constants as frequently as I like and obviously the most recent constants will be used when I run the equation.

The equation is easy to program but now I have to work out how to derive the figures within PHP or JQuery (apologies for not mentioning which language I intend to use).

I've looked into R but I'd like to do this in vanilla php if possible.

Comment: @Jelby-John: If you google "php linear regression", that should give you some pointers.

Comment: I have been and still am. I found a good article at [opensourcetutorials](http://www.opensourcetutorials.com/tutorials/Server-Side-Coding/PHP/simple-linear-regression-php-1/page7.html) for a custom PHP class but am also considering installing R and using a shell_exec. I will feedback my progress. Thank you.