# Predicting system performance - method for extrapolating multivariate performance metrics into perdictive equation

Tags: performance, regression, prediction, forecasting

I have a reporting application. Its performance is dependent on the hardware it is hosted on and the data it runs against. So under hardware, the main factors are:

- CPU cores
- Memory
- Hard disk speed

.. and under data, the main factors are:

- Number of customers
- The average amount of data each customer has generated

My plan is to run a series of tests to measure the performance when I alter a single factor. So, for example, I will run the performance tests against 1 core, 2 cores and 4 cores and then run the tests against 4GB RAM, 16GB RAM and 64GB RAM.

From these measurements I would like to produce a formula that can roughly predict how well a system will perform given certain hardware and data.

For example:

> **Performance Score = f(cpu) + g(mem) + h(disk) + j(cust) + k(data)**
>
> *where f, g, h, j and k are functions of the parameter they are passed.*

My question is:

**Is there a formal method for taking performance metrics as an input and extrapolating that data to produce a formula that predicts performance?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - I would use [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) as a starting point.

For an example, see [How can I predict memory usage and time based on historical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437430/how-can-i-predict-memory-usage-and-time-based-on-historical-values).

I found [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Analytical/dp/052168689X) to be s highly readable introduction to the subject (you probably won't need multilevel models, so you can skip the second part of the book).

Comment: Linear regression and approach you mentioned is application specific. It will vary according to application behavior, usage. I think first of all you should analyze the system very well by doing some sample test. find out linear regression will suit or not.