# How to predict a possible performance issue in a web service's performance?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, cpu-usage, heap-memory

We have multiple web services, each running inside a Docker container hosted on a Kubernetes cluster. We basically want a way to predict based on the system metrics for a given service, whether or not the system performance is impacted at any given point in time. I have minute by minute metrics, like, response time, used/max/committed heap (for both young and old Gen), throughput, garbage collection CPU Utilization %, CPU Utilization %, etc. Is there a way to use such historical data to predict possible issues with the web service?

I'm new to concepts of Machine Learning, but I was reading about Predictive Analysis that can be done on data which is mainly time based to come up with the future forecast using techniques like Linear Regression. I came across a [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437430/how-can-i-predict-memory-usage-and-time-based-on-historical-values) on stack overflow which does talk about something similar, but I'm still not very clear with the approach that should be taken for such kind of predictions or if it is even a good idea to do it or not.

Comment: What programming language or statistical software package would you prefer?

Comment: Programming language is not a restriction for us here. From my observation so far, I believe R and Python are the most preferred. Python would be a better option for us out of the two.